# Запись hex в бинарный файл

Tags: python, windows

Как можно записать hex в бинарный файл? 
Т.е задача такая: есть hex строка бинарного файла, мне надо с помощью скрипта записать эту hex строку в .exe файл.

Типа такой строки:

4d5a90000300000004000000ffff0000b800000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000e1fba0e00b409cd21b8014ccd215468

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
hex_str = '4d5a90000300000004000000ffff ... 0000100000e1fba0e00b409cd21b8014ccd215468'
with open('some.exe', wb) as fh:
    fh.write(bytes.fromhex(hex_str))
```